# SpringBoot w/ Thymeleaf "GET Resource not found"

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

1. When I click the link in **home.html** , Spring says **GET - Resource not found**.
2. You'll see in home.th.xml it says to yell at the Mappings (and I presume thats how the @GetMapping serves catalog-home).

[EDIT] Added DecoupledLogic.java to project
[EDIT] Added MvcConfig file (was existing in project)

---

MvcConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName(ViewNames.HOME);
        registry.addViewController("home").setViewName(ViewNames.HOME);
    }
}
```

BookCatalogController.java

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class BookCatalogController {

    // == Request methods ==

    // Catalog Simple View
    @GetMapping("Mappings.CATALOG_SIMPLE")
    public String catalogSimple(Model model){

        log.info("catalogSimple method called");

        return ViewNames.CATALOG_SIMPLE;
    }
```

Mappings.java

```
// For mapping LINKS to views
public class Mappings {

    // Welcome homepage
    public static final String HOME = "home";

    // Catalog views
    public static final String CATALOG_SIMPLE="catalog-simple";
    // psfs CATALOG_DETAIL = "catalog-detail";

    //== constructor
    private Mappings(){}


}
```

ViewNames.java

```
public class ViewNames {

    public static final String HOME = "home";

    public static final String CATALOG_SIMPLE="catalog-simple";

    //==constructor
    private ViewNames(){}
}
```

catalog-simple.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head id="headId">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title content</title>
    </head>
    <body>
HELLO
    </body>
</html>
```

DecoupledLogic.java

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class DecoupledLogicSetup {

    // == fields ==
    private final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver;

    // == constructor
    public DecoupledLogicSetup(SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        this.templateResolver = templateResolver;
    }

    // == init ==
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        templateResolver.setUseDecoupledLogic(true);
        log.info("Decoupled template logic enabled");
    }
}
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head id="headId">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title content</title>
</head>
<body>


<div align="center">
    <h1 id="welcomeMessage"></h1>


    <h3>
        <a id="goToCatalogSimple"
        href="catalog-simple.html">Go to catalog
        </a>
    </h3>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

home.th.xml

```
    <attr sel="#goToCatalogSimple"
          th:href="@{__${T(com.potatospy.bookcatalog.util.Mappings).CATALOG_SIMPLE}__}"
          th:text="#{bc.welcome.gosimplecatalog}"/>
</thlogic>
```

LOG

```
2019-01-18 18:31:35.154 DEBUG 10948 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/catalog-simple", parameters={}
2019-01-18 18:31:35.155 DEBUG 10948 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2019-01-18 18:31:35.156 DEBUG 10948 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-01-18 18:31:35.157 DEBUG 10948 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
```

Comment: Stupid question: How do you access home.html? I can't see any home controller?

Comment: @simon-martinelli Thanks. Adding that file to the question

Comment: Have you added it?

Comment: Yes I added that + DecoupledLogic which is supposed to be in there to support the .th.xml files I think

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I'm... disappointed but I had QUOTES around my @ GetMapping .... removed quotes...so not its actually pointed at my Mappings file instead of trying to use this bogus string I forced it to use

Comment: Happy you found the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your controller class, `BookCatalogController` you declare the method `catalogSimple` to accept requests, and you should there define the route. Instead of `@GetMapping("Mappings.CATALOG_SIMPLE")`, use `@GetMapping("/home")`.

Comment: Unforunately, that made no difference to the error... in fact it was very surprising to see the log is identical to that of the log before! That's fishy in and of itself

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this but....

In my BookCatalogController.java
I have QUOTES around my @GetMapping param

@GetMapping("donPutQuoteAroundThisParam")

so now I Have

```
@GetMapping(Mappings.CATALOG_SIMPLE)
```